# Integrating Gaussian with standard deviation in formula

Tags: integration

$P(x) = e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$

I have struggled to find online resources to help me with this as all they do is integrate $e^{-x^2}$ and never any other variation. Do I need to exclude $2\sigma^2$ or keep it constant while I integrate the rest normally or do I have to do something different?

Comment: The Gausian is a tricky function to integrate.  It doesn't integrate into elementary functions.  Instead there is the error function (erf). http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html However, it is not quite so hard to find the improper integral. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \ dx$

Comment: @DougM Thank you so much :)!